# `ng-model` of AngularStrap `bs-typeahead` not available in scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-strap

I am running into an issue with the value of `ng-model`, applied to an element using AngularStrap's `bs-typeahead`, is not accessible within scope. It is however viable from a `{{ var }}` within the HTML.

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="add a destination" ng-options="item as item for item in modelTypeahead" ng-model="selectedDestination" bs-typeahead data-template="templates/SrcDstTypeaheadTemplate.html">
```

I initialize the variable in my controller:

```
$scope.selectedDestination = "";
```

Placing a `{{ selectedDestination }}` elsewhere within the HTML works as expected.

However, when I do a `console.log($scope.selectedDestination);` within my controller it comes out as an empty string.

If I update my initialization to be something, for example:

```
$scope.selectedDestination = "abc123";
```

... both the `<input>` and the `{{ selectedDestination }}` update appropriately. My `console.log` will also spit out the set value. However, if I update the typeahead the `{{ selectDestination }}` will update but my `console.log` will spit out 'abc123' still.

Is there a scope issue that I am missing? I don't understand how `{{ selectedDestination }}` is putting out the correct string but the `console.log` is putting out something different. It would almost seem my binding is one-way, but AngularStrap's `bs-typeahead` should be two-way (per all the examples).

Comment: experiencing exactly the same problem. have you solved it?

Comment: No. It appears that selection from the typeahead are not propagating fully. I have not discovered exactly how/why.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing `console.log`?  You would have to make sure that the value has changed before you do that for the value to show up, you could do:

```
$scope.watch('selectedDestination', function() { 
    console.log($scope.selectedDestination); 
});
```

Comment: I've done it all over. Most recently, I do it on a button press (just for testing purposes). I added the `$watch` code above and it never fires as I type or confirm typeahead selections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still running into any issues with this, but I found a solution to the exact same problem when I ran into it just recently. I'm almost positive that its a scope issue or apply failure within the AngularStrap stuff, but I wouldn't know where to start looking.

Really, I'm not educated enough to give you the exact reasons that this works, but this is what you do:

**(1)** You change the variable to an object.

*when you put the model and watch on an object instead of a top layer variable, it works better through layers of directives. Don't ask me why....*

**(2)** Use a deep watch on the object you just created.

*When you change it to an object, you need to use a [deep watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on the variable or the $apply and $digest won't pick up any changes. This is because by default the value will be checked for "reference" equality instead of "value" equality. This breaks because the object's "reference" doesn't change, only its values. But be careful using this deep comparison because the extra effort can cause a lot of overhead.*

Here's an example in use with AngularStrap's typeahead:

```
$scope.selectedDestination = {};

~~~

<input type="text" placeholder="add a destination" ng-options="item as item for item in modelTypeahead" ng-model="selectedDestination.destination" bs-typeahead data-template="templates/SrcDstTypeaheadTemplate.html">

~~~

$scope.$watch('selectedDestination', function(value) {
  console.log('selectedDestination', $scope.subComponent);
}, true); //here we need to tell the watch to do a deep watch
```

**EDIT** I've traced my issues back to a few things, but part of it was the $render function. I'll keep looking into it. Good luck!